# Roslyn Analyzer Check if Property Declaration is a Standard Type (int, string, Guid, etc)

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using Roslyn Analyzer to analyze code and I want to check if a Property Declaration is a Standard Type (for example, string, int, Guid, DateTime, etc).

For example I want to analyze the below Code:

```
namespace myApp.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public MyOtherModel MyOtherModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyOtherModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can get all property declarations by using:

```
var node = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(aboveCodeAsString).GetRoot();
IEnumerable<ClassDeclarationSyntax> classDeclarationSyntaxes = node.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
var propertyDeclarations = classDeclarationSyntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();
foreach (var propertyDeclaration in propertyDeclarations)
{
    ...
}
```

What I need is function IsStandardType(PropertyDeclarationSyntax propertyDeclarationSyntax) that returns true for:

```
public int myInt { get; set; }
public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
```

But false for:

```
public MyOtherClass myOtherModel { get; set; }
```

In this case all models will be in the same namespace so a possible solution is to compare the namespace of all property declarations to the namespace of the model. If they are not equal, then I know it is a Standard Type.

But, I am also having trouble getting the namespace of a property declaration (for example System.DateTime in case of "public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }" so I need help with that too.

All models are however in different files so this might not be the best solution.

Comment: I think to do what you want in a meaningful way you will want to use the semantic model, rather than syntax model, so that you can look at the types and see what assemblies or namespaces they belong to.

Comment: Hallo Stuart! That is fine for me. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what do you mean by "Standard Type".
Does it mean all BCL types? FCL types? all types that not declared in your assembly?

Anyway, you could solve it by examining the ContainingNamespace\Assembly property (depends on your requirements).

For example, if all types except those declared in your assembly, considering as standard types, then you can write:

```
model.GetDeclaredSymbol(propertyDeclaration).Type.ContainingAssembly
```